# Aurelia `@dynamicOptions` mixed with `@bindable`s

Tags: aurelia

I am developing using aureliajs. By now I am working on a custom attribute which has marked to have dynamic options. For example consider following code:

```
  import {dynamicOptions, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

  @dynamicOptions
  @inject(Element)
  export class SquareCustomAttribute {
    constructor(element){
      this.element = element;
    }

    propertyChanged(name, newValue, oldValue){
      switch(name){
        case 'fill':
          this.element.style.backgroundColor = newValue;
          break;
        case 'size':
          this.element.style.width = this.element.style.height = `${newValue}px`;
          break;
        default:
          this.element.style[name] = newValue;
          break;
      }
    }
  }
```

now for example consider that I want to give the property fill, `defaultBindingMode` of twoWay, so I will try to add the `@bindable` property in class. So the code will change to this:

```
  import {dynamicOptions, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

  @dynamicOptions
  @inject(Element)
  export class SquareCustomAttribute {
    @bindable fill;

    constructor(element){
      this.element = element;
    }

    propertyChanged(name, newValue, oldValue){
      switch(name){
        case 'fill':
          this.element.style.backgroundColor = newValue;
          break;
        case 'size':
          this.element.style.width = this.element.style.height = `${newValue}px`;
          break;
        default:
          this.element.style[name] = newValue;
          break;
      }
    }
  }
```

And binding stops working.

1. So, the first question is how to set defaultBindingMode for dynamicOptions?
2. And another little question. As [aurelia.io](https://aurelia.io) says, `Binding to a dynamic options attribute works exactly the same as binding to an options attribute in the DOM.`. According to this sentence, I expect to bind dynamic options dash seperated and retrieve the in camel case on `optionsChanged` method. But dash seperated options bound from view, receives dash separated and camels, camels. Is this correct according to referenced sentence from [aurelia.io](https://aurelia.io)?

Comment: This could probably be a bug in Aurelia. If so, I will PR to fix it soon. Reproduction at https://codesandbox.io/s/ov5yyw7q2z.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @bigopon, this issue is being followed up in [this issue](https://github.com/aurelia/framework/issues/937) and I think any additional comment on that will be beneficial before making changes on aurelia-framework.